# Does restoring a full backup bring it to the backup START time or the backup FINISH time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

Backstory: I'm trying to restore copies of several SQL 2012 databases to a different environment, but the application needs them to be (roughly) "synchronized" in time.

(Of course the *ideal* way to do this is by using FULL recovery mode using full and log backups, and then do point-in time restores using the same timestamp. But in my case, I don't need them *perfectly* synchronized, just within ~10 minutes or so, and I'd rather deal with only full backups and restores. I do have control over when the full backups run, but the problem is that the databases are of very different sizes, so the full backups run for very different lengths of time.)

So my question: should I synchronize the *start time* of the full backups? Or the *finish time*?

In other words, **when I restore a full backup, will I end up with how it looked when the backup *started*, or when it *finished*?**

Comment: you can use [**transaction marks**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117743/8783) when taking backups and to recover them to a logically consistent point. I have used that for sharepoint databases and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx#id0980008)

> A full database backup provides a complete copy of the database and
>   provides a single point-in-time to which the database can be restored.
>   Even though it may take many hours for the backup process to run, you
>   can still only restore the backup to a single point (effectively at
>   the end of the backup, but I'll discuss exactly what that point is
>   later in this article). A full backup does not allow recovery to any
>   point in time while the backup was running.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very on-point quote. For anyone who doesn't want to read the whole thing, Randal clarifies later on that the "exact point" is when the backup process is *finished reading the data files*, but before it reads through the tran log to capture transactions that ran during the full backup. So, pretty much the finish time.

Comment: The full backup also utilizes the records in the tail log. Does that mean the backup contains data uptill the last completed transaction? If so, then in your comment above, why do you say "before it reads through the tran log to capture transactions that ran during the full backup"?

Comment: @variable Say a backup started at 10pm, finished reading the data files at 11pm, and took an additional 2 minutes to capture the tail log before the backup completed. Restoring that backup would bring you to how it looked at 11:00pm not 11:02pm (or 10pm). So it does *use* the tail log in the backup, but it uses it to bring you back to the moment just before it starts reading the tail log, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @BradC - please can you advise why does it use the tail log during backup? Is this related to undo/redo transactions?

Comment: @variable It uses it to capture all the activity that was going on during the time it was reading the data files for backup. So in my example above, the completed transactions between 10pm and 11pm.

Comment: But it has found everything till 11PM in the data pages - so why look at log records?

Comment: @variable Changes may have occurred in tables read during earlier parts of the backup, and the backup captures those changes by reading the tran log (rather than going back and re-reading the data files). Remember for a RDBMS like SQL that is built upon ACID principles, its not good enough for different tables in a backup to represent different points in time; the restore has to be able to bring the entire database back to a single internally-consistent point-in time.

Comment: Does full backup by itself (without log back up files) support point in time recovery?

Comment: @variable No, if all you have is a full backup, your only recovery option is to do a full restore, which (as this answer explains) takes you back to (near) the end of when the full backup was taken. You'll need both full and tran log backups if you want to choose the exact time to restore to (you're not limited to when the tran log backups were taken; you can select any moment in time as your restore point)

Comment: Assuming I have full backup as of Sunday 12AM and Tlog backups of every 1 hour after Sunday 12AM, then the point in time recovery is possible only for Sunday 12AM onwards correct?

Answer (score 6):

A Sql Server backup contains all allocated data pages and enough of the transaction log so a restore operation can recover the database so it is transactionally consistent as of the point in time **when the read data operation completed**.

So, to answer your question

> What is the “moment” of a full backup? The START time or the FINISH
>   time?

It's the **FINISH** time.

It should be very easy to prove this to yourself by invoking a backup operation, making some changes to some data while the backup is running (making sure to commit them) and then restore that backup somewhere and check for your changes.

Referencing [More on how much transaction log a full backup includes](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/more-on-how-much-transaction-log-a-full-backup-includes/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would consider Paul Randal an authoritative reference on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Any SQL backup is done when it writes the backup end time to the backupset table in the msdb database. When you search in there full backups are type D and log backups are type L. And there is a copy-only column to mark copy-only backups

I run the following query periodically against a group I created on our central management server and you can modify it for your needs.

```
select  a.server_name as hostname,   a.Database_Name,a.name, 
a.backup_finish_date
--over (partition by database_name) 
as Backup_End_Time
,Backup_Type = 
case a.type
when 'D' then 'Full backup'
when 'I' then 'Differential Backup'
when 'L' then 'Transaction Log Backup'
when 'F' then 'filegroup Backup'
when 'G' then 'Differential File backup'
else 'See Books Online'
end, cast((a.backup_size/1048576)as bigint) as Size_of_Backup_MB , 
a.software_major_version, a.compatibility_level, a.has_backup_checksums, 
a.is_copy_only
from msdb..backupset a
inner join sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states b on 
a.server_name = b.replica_server_name
--inner join sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states e on 
d.server_name = e.replica_server_name
inner join sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states c on c.replica_id = 
b.replica_id
inner join sys.databases e on a.database_name = e.name
where exists 
(select 1 from msdb..backupset d
            where a.server_name = d.server_name 
                and a.database_name = d.database_name
                and d.is_copy_only = 0
                having a.backup_finish_date = max(d.backup_finish_date))
 and a.Type = 'd'
 --and a.name in ('CommVault Galaxy Backup')
 --and a.has_backup_checksums = 0
 --and c.role_desc = 'primary'
 group by a.backup_finish_date, a.database_name, a.server_name, a.Type, 
 a.backup_size, a.compatibility_level, a.database_version, 
 a.software_major_version
 , a.has_backup_checksums, a.is_copy_only, a.name, a.description
 having max(a.backup_finish_date) < getdate() -2
 order by a.server_name, a.database_name
```

Comment: What OP is asking is how to make backup synchronized between different databases ... Also, based on your edit .. you need to remove `and a.name in ('CommVault Galaxy Backup')`

Comment: I know how to find the start and finish *times*, but my question is about whether a restore will *include all the transactions that occurred between the start time and finish time*, or whether full backups do some sort of snapshot thing and therefore contain the database *as it was when the backup began*.

Comment: I have a bunch of AlwaysOn clusters in a CMS group I run this against. I usually run this to make sure Commvault isn't skipping anything but sometimes I comment out the next to last line to get all the backups. OP can comment it out and run this against the servers he needs to compare and it will let him/her know when the backups complete on each server.

Comment: Sorry, that's a nice script, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: As I understand it the full backup will read the transaction log and backup the transactions that take place during the full backup. Any transaction that doesn't complete will be rolled back during the restore. Backupset also has the LSN's so you can track which ones are backed up.

Comment: I've worked in 24x7 shops where there are changes to databases literally every minute. Very little changes via applications during the night, but I've seen some databases with most of their changes in the 2am and 3am time frame via automated jobs running at night. If something happens and the data isn't in the backup, then you rerun the job after a restore.

Comment: Of course there are conflicting requirements! But my point still stands: you wrote `backup is done when it writes the backup end time to the backupset table in the msdb database`. This implies to me that backups are the state of the db at the **end** of the backup. I am saying that the backup is a snapshot of the db at the **beginning** of the backup.

Comment: @Vérace Check out the links in the other 2 answers (to someone I consider an authoritative source, a former member of the SQL engine team at MS) saying that "end time" is correct.Sounds like a full backup simply includes enough transaction log so it can complete any transactions that were in-flight (and roll back any that did not complete before the end of the full backup).

Comment: Gotcha - I shouldn't have opened my mouth! :-( I'm deleting what I wrote above - I believe that there are servers where the backup is from the startpoint - but I'm obviously wrong about MS SQL Server!