# how to integrate ola hallengren solution with log shipping?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2017, log-shipping, ola-hallengren

I need to set up log-shipping from my SQLPROD2 to server2

but I am facing the following problems:

1) I already use ola hallegren backup solution, and it provides the 15 min log backups for all databases - can I use this job instead of the job the log shipping wants me to use?

or alternatively should I remove the databases that I add to the log shipping from the Ola's user database backup job?

2) what about the full backups that I take once a day?
would that mess up the log shipping? should I do a full backup with copy_only?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Ola's solution, its intelligent to exclude log shipping dbs. See [FAQs](https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html)

> **Does the SQL Server Maintenance Solution support log shipping?**
>
> The SQL Server Maintenance Solution supports log shipping. Full and differential backup, integrity check, and index and statistics maintenance are performed on the primary database. Transaction log backups are not performed on databases that are involved in log shipping.

.

> what about the full backups that I take once a day? would that mess up the log shipping? should I do a full backup with copy_only?

A full backup wont break log backup chain. Only an additional NON COPY_ONLY log backup will break the log chain.

If you have folks taking adhoc log backups, you can [DENY BACKUP LOG to [user|group]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64306/8783)